# Inductive reactance: frequency vs current. Why current goes to zero as frequency increases?

Tags: ac, frequency, reactance, frequency-response

Suppose I have the circuit below with the frequency of the voltage source as a free parameter. Assuming the inductance is constant, the current flowing through the circuit shoud equal

$$I(f) = \frac{V}{j2\pi fL + R}$$

(I'm using phasors). Then by increasing the frequency up to infinity the current goes to zero. Why is this happening? I mean it is probably clear to me from a mathematical point of view and by using the frequency response I guess the absolute value of the trasfer function is going down as f tends to infinity, but what is the physical explanation behind this effect of a high frequency?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyR5Zz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate you accepting my answer, but you shouldn't do that so quickly.  Now you'll never know what others might have said.  It's usually good to wait a day or so to see what collects.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I accepted it because I think it is very clear in explaining the physical reason which is what I was interested in. However you are right, next time I'll wait a little longer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to look at this is that the inductor is a frequency-variable resistor (not quite since there's also a phase shift in there, but that's not important for this point).  The higher the frequency, the higher the resistance.  At the same voltage, the inductor draws less current at higher frequencies.

A totally different way to think of this is to visualize what the inductor is doing, going back to how inductors work.  If you apply a fixed voltage across a inductor, the current will rise linearly.  Put another way, it takes time for the current to build up.  Now imagine that you keep switching polarities of the voltage.  The current builds up linearly in one direction.  When the voltage flips, the current then linearly decreases to 0, then builds up to ever higher magnitude in the other direction as long as the voltage persists.  Put yet another way, the maximum current is a function of how long you keep the voltage before flipping.

Now consider AC is like the flipping voltage.  Higher frequencies means faster flipping, which means the current has less time to change between flips.  As the frequency gets higher, the inductor has less time to build up current between flips, and the average magnitude of the current will be less.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation was really clear, I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

To also explain it on the actual physical level: any current in a coil causes a magnetic field. In case of DC current, the magnetic field doesn't have any further effects, but an AC current will also cause the field to *change* all the time, and that causes an [induced voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction) in those same coil windingings, proportional to the time-derivative of the magnetic field, i.e. proportional to \$I\cdot f\$.

But now, in your application the voltage amplitude is actually limited by the supply, so the only way the law can be fulfilled at very high frequencies is if the current stays very small. Any substantial \$I\$ would cause \$I\cdot f\$ and thus the voltage to blow up towards infinity, in the high-frequency limit.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, an inductor is a coil wire whose resistance is zero. Therefore, at zero frequency (DC current) the inductor no opposition to current.
The voltage on the inductor, assuming that the inductance thereof is constant, is given by

\$
v_L = L\,\dfrac{di}{dt}
\$

that is, [the voltage across the inductor depends on the rate of change of current through it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Constitutive_equation).

The higher the frequency, the greater the rate of change and the greater the voltage across the inductor. In the limiting case of infinite frequency, the rate of change is infinite and therefore, the inductor behaves like an open circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand that capacitors are **pretty much the inverse of inductors**, and can understand that for a capacitor the current goes to zero as the frequency goes to zero, a lightbulb may come on.

Capacitors seem to be more intuitive for most people.

Comment: Everyone has taken a bath, but only some houses have water hammer. ;)